# Inserting uuid into sqlite Database in node doesnt work

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I am currently working on inserting a uuid-value like this one:
c1f9ff70-71e8-11eb-8b1b-77c34b246f91
into a sqlite database. This is my insert-Statement:

```
    this.db.serialize(() => {
        this.db.prepare(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bestellung(bid BLOB PRIMARY KEY, drink TEXT,price REAL,validation TEXT)`).run().finalize();
    });
     //FUNKTIONIERT!
    const bidJSON = getBID();
    const name = 'Testdrink';
    const preis = 12.90;
    const kpreis = preis.toFixed(2);
    preis.toFixed(2);
    console.log(bidJSON.id);
    console.log(name);
    console.log(kpreis);
    var statement = "INSERT INTO bestellung(bid, drink, price, validation) VALUES(`" + bidJSON.id + "`,`" + name + "`,`" + kpreis + "`, `pending`)";
    this.db.prepare(statement);
```

This is the error I get:

```
[Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: c1f9ff70-71e8-11eb-8b1b-77c34b246f91
Emitted 'error' event on Statement instance at:
] {
  errno: 1,
  code: 'SQLITE_ERROR'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bk@0.0.0 start: `node app`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bk@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\prakt\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-18T12_56_46_751Z-debug.log
```

I hope someone can help me!
For experienced programmers it should be an easy task.
I think it will probably be a mistake in my statement. I already read, that you can save the uuid into a blob and that this is the fastest way of saving it...
so i would like to stick to that.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're supposed to use backticks to wrap column names that are also reserved sql words, string values are supposed to be wrapped with quotes (and just quotes). So you could use `\`bid\`` instead of `bid` in the set of columns for instance, but you need to remove them from the set of values. You also need `"pending"`.

Comment: sry my english isnt the best. I think this is what you tried to say: `
    var statement = "INSERT INTO bestellung(``bid``, ``drink``, ``price``, ``validation``) VALUES(" + bidJSON.id + "," + name + "," + kpreis + ","+ " pending)";
    this.db.prepare(statement); `so essentially i put a "tick" around every columnname. And the rest is usually surrounded by " "

Comment: still: [Error: SQLITE_ERROR: unrecognized token: "4c4bb570"
Emitted 'error' event on Statement instance at:
] {
  errno: 1,
  code: 'SQLITE_ERROR'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bk@0.0.0 start: `node app`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bk@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\prakt\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-18T13_29_16_798Z-debug.log

Comment: This time you don't have any delimiting characters around your strings. Here's fixed code: https://jsfiddle.net/4hm2310q/

Comment: And here's something I like to use: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/4wz3kfbp/

Comment: I really appreciate your help! Im also sorry to say that it still doesnt work out. This is my create: this.db.serialize(() => {
        this.db.prepare(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bestellung(bid BLOB PRIMARY KEY, drink TEXT,price REAL,validation TEXT)`).run().finalize();
    });      it works fine.

Comment: This is my Insert now:    this.db.run('INSERT INTO bestellung (`bid`, `drink`, `price`, `validation`) VALUES ("c1f9ff70-71e8-11eb-8b1b-77c34b246f91", "Testdrink", 12.90, "pending")', ['C'], (err) => {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err.message);
        }
        console.log('Row was added to the table: ${this.lastID}');
    })  and this is the error this function returns: SQLITE_RANGE: column index out of range

Comment: i googled the error, but i didnt get anything useable. The BLOB should work for uuid. Just as the other datatypes should do for their values. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: You could try using a basic id as index instead maybe, but I don't really know what's causing the error.

Comment: Well thank you Chris! I really apreciate your help!